# Accessor Methods for Arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

I have an object that stores arrays as instance variables. Since Perl does not seem to support this, I have to store references to the arrays instead. However, I cannot figure out how to mutate these arrays once they have been created; the methods seem to change only the local copy. (Currently, at the end of addOwnedFile(), the object data is unchanged).

```
sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my @owned_files = ();
    my @shared_files = ();

    my $self = {

        #$[0] is the class
        _name => $_[1],
        _owned_files => \[],
        _shared_files => \[],        
    };
    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
    }




#Add a file to the list of files that a user owns
sub addOwnedFile {
    my ($self, $file) = @_;
        my $ref = $self -> {_owned_files};
        my @array = @$ref;

        push(@array, $file);

        push(@array, "something");

        push(@{$self->{_owned_files}}, "something else");

        $self->{_owned_files} = \@array;
}
```

Comment: Read [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you posted triggers a runtime *"Not an ARRAY reference..."* error. The reason is that sets `_owned_files` to `\[]` which is not an array reference but rather a reference to an array reference. Drop the `\` from both array attributes.

With that out of the way, we can get to the next problem. `@array` is a copy of the anonymous array held by the object. Your first two `push`es are to the copy, the last to the held array. You then clobber the held array by replacing it with a reference to the copy. It's best to just work with the original array via the reference. Either of the following would work:

```
push @$ref, 'something';
push @{$self->{_owned_files}}, 'something';
```

And drop the

```
$self->{_owned_files} = \@array;
```

at the end.

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $name  = shift;
    my $self  = {
        _name         => $name,
        _owned_files  => [],
        _shared_files => [],
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub addOwnedFile {
    my ($self, $file) = @_;
    push @{$self->{_shared_files}}, $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure the issue you have in in the

```
my $self = {
    #$[0] is the class
    _name => $_[1],
    _owned_files => \[],
    _shared_files => \[],        
};
```

section. `_owned_file=> \[]` will not create and array reference but rather a reference to a reference to an array. Rather what you want is `_owned_files => []`. Same for shared files.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work, with [], \(), or \@owned_arrays. I've also tried push @$ref "something".